# Unity build issue over 16+ hours

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, compiler-errors, shader, urp

So has anyone had this issue, ever since I've updated my graphics card (doubt that is the cause)

Building the unity project, takes an insane amount of time, its not stuck the shader variants are slowly compiling.

The issue is that this has never happened before, the build times usually range between 10 minutes and 3-4 hours on clean builds.

Any ideas, has anyone had issue before?

- If I go out and build each individual scene on their own, it takes about 5-10 minutes.
- If I build multiple scenes, still about 10-20 minutes.
- If build all them.. the building process seems to slow to a halt.

I've changed things in the player settings, made sure optimize mesh has been checked off in player settings.

I've even purchased the asset shader control, which has haha... done nothing.

EDIT:.... So... it built... after 2 hours now. I don't know what I did differently, other than building every scene individually ... and setting every shader compiler process to high... unity man.

Comment: Does it finish now? You may find some clues from the editor log. [Check how many shader variants you have](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/shader-how-many-variants.html). Try to use `shader_feature` instead of `multi_compile`.

Comment: .... So... it built... after 2 hours now. I don't know what I did differently, other than building every scene individually ... and setting every shader compiler process to high.